# Merging files in R and keeping column on which I do the match?

Tags: r

I have two huge data tables:

```
> head(x)
          gene_id chr  min_POS  max_POS     rs_id pvalue_G pvalue_E     metaP
1 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776  rs319690   0.7139   0.8613 0.7019270
2 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776 rs4392441   0.5452   0.7074 0.4881783
3 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776 rs4858887   0.5435   0.7074 0.4870446
4 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776 rs7651237   0.8621   0.6440 0.6529929
5 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776 rs6803741   0.5436   0.6612 0.4596804
6 ENSG00000047849   3 47568061 48143776 rs4858881   0.6142   0.6833 0.5189457
...

> head(b)
          V2        V3    V4 V5 V6
1: 194857581 194857582 rs224  0  -
2: 194857560 194857561 rs225  0  -
3:   7864903   7864904 rs226  0  +
4:   7864919   7864920 rs227  0  +
5:   5558441   5558442 rs228  0  +
6: 137923628 137923629 rs229  0  +
...
```

I am trying to merge them, using:

```
x1=merge(b, x, by.x = "V4", by.y="rs_id")
```

the issue is that I would like to keep all V4 and rs_id on which I merged on. This merge gave me 89 rows in x1 and I would like to have an additional column which would have all those matching V4 and rs_id.

Also b file is huge so any more efficient way would be welcome.

Basically I need to match x and b on V4 and rs_id and columns whcih I need to keep in final data frame are: gene_id,chr, rs_id (matched),pvalue_G, pvalue_E,V2,V3.

Comment: It is always advisable to post expected output in code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try package dplyr for this. I am doing this as hopefully real code, but have not ran it since I do not have the data frames.

Basically we are doing an **inner join** with x and b (so keeping only rows with a matching rs_ID and V4) and then selecting the columns we want.

library(dplyr)

```
x %>%
  inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
  select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3)
```

Comment: Hi, I got: > x %>%
+   inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4") %>%
+   select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue,_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3)
Error: unexpected input in:
"  inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4") %>%
  select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue,_"

Comment: whoops i think i was missing a closing ')'. editing it now.

Comment: > x %>%
+   inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
+   select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue,_G, pvalue_E, V2, V3)
Error: unexpected input in:
"  inner_join(b, by = c("rs_id" = "V4")) %>%
  select(gene_id, chr, rs_id, pvalue,_"

Comment: something about this is not right: by = c("rs_id" = "V4")

Comment: oh. sorry again... comma after pvalue,_G. Loaded the data in, tested it, should work. your header set has no overlapping IDs though so I get 0 rows.

Comment: it happens in speed. Great and so fast solution. Thanks!